# How to store the file name selected in the program

Tags: matlab, user-interface

How do we find the name of the selected file name and store it a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the function [uigetfile](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uigetfile.html) to get the name of the selected file. This syntax would work:

```
 filename = uigetfile
```